# ddev Database Import not showing up in phpMyAdmin

Tags: ddev

I've setup ddev for a Silverstripe PHP project, with existing files. I can get to the site.  I can get to the phpmyadmin link given by ddev describe and I have ran ddev import-db successfully.

When I go to the site's ddev link, I get missing table errors and the phpMyAdmin is not showing any of the imported data.

What am I missing to get the database that the CLI is using to be the one the browser based site & phpMyAdmin are using?

Comment: Great to have you working with Silverstripe! 

If you `ddev ssh` and then run `mysql`, and `SHOW TABLES;` do you see the expected tables? Is it possible that your import file does not have the expected contents in it, or that it specifies a different database? I'd recommend poking around with mysql to see what happened. Note that you can also import inside either the web container or the db container just using `mysql`.

Comment: Hi! It says :  Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: ok, so thanks.  I edited the sql import to not specify a db.  I then had a couple of things to fix in the silverstripe setup, ssh into the webroot and run "php framework/cli-script.php dev/build "  and it's working.

Comment: well, except .htaccess doesn't seem to work?

Comment: .htaccess is a feature of Apache. The default webserver_type in ddev is nginx. So change the webserver_type in .ddev/config.yaml to `apache-fpm` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'd love it if you would write up your setup for ddev on Stack Overflow. Ask the question "How do I set up the Silverstripe CMS with ddev?" and ask the question, then click the checkbox to answer your own question, and give a detailed set up setup instructions. That would be awesome!

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It works! ill do that